# How can I do combinatorics in PHP?

Tags: php, combinatorics

I'm not too familiar with combinatorics, but I need to calculate `C(m,n)` using PHP. What's an easy way to do find `C(m,n)`?

Comment: Do you have problems *understanding combinatorics*, *implementing an algorithm* or *looking for an existing function*?

Comment: Preferably an existing function to calculate C(m,n) using PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it using formulas on Wikipedia. This should work:

```
function fact($n){
  $f=$n--;
  while($n>0)
    $f*=$n--;
  return $f;
}


function c($n,$m){
  return fact($n)/(fact($m)*fact($n-$m));
}

echo c(6,3);
```

Please let me know if there's something wrong with my function, thanks!

Comment: These functions will do what you desire. The factorial is pretty straight forward, it could also be done recursively as well. The c() function will compute combinations with repetitions.

Comment: You're looking for `C(m,n)` but that implementation is written `c($n,$m)` so it looks like you switched the names here. Also please leave a link to the wikipedia article you got this from.

Answer (score 0):

The factorial must return 1 in case the result is 0.

```
    function fact($n){
      $f=$n--;
      while($n>0)
        $f*=$n--;
      if($f==0){
        return 1;
      }
      return $f;
    }
```